# Using the mysql commands from one docker container to another

Tags: mysql, docker

I created a network in docker and connected two docker containers to the same network. One container is the application container and the other is the database container. I checked if the ping is happening between the two containers, it was successful. Now, how do I run the MySQL commands from application container?

The container Ip of Mysql is 172.17.0.3
The container Ip of Application is 172.17.0.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple containers, I suggest some tool to organize them, like Docker Compose, Docker Swarm, Kubernetes, etc. This way, you can completely forget about containers IPs, networks and connections are easily created and managed, etc.

For example, your stack on DockerCompose would be like:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql

  app:
    # Use ./ as Docker Build context path
    build: .
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'db'
      # So you don't have to use root, but you can if you like
      MYSQL_USER: 'user'
      # You can use whatever password you like
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      # Password for root access
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'

# Names our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

You can even move database connection parameters to a `.env` and use its values from the YAML above.

In this example, the container named `app` can access the MySQL database using the `mysql` hostname. It will be automatically populated inside the container `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: anyway, I can do without docker compose?

Comment: You could, but then you'll need to track MySQL container IP using some script and add it to the app container run command with something like `docker run --add-host=mysql:${docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mysql} --rm -it my-app`. You'll need to add the `mysql` name to the DB container, or get it's ID when launching it and using it instead.

Comment: This this solved or helped solving your issue?

Comment: I used the docker --link for this and it was happening! Thanks!!!